# sum of cost spent on advertisments on specific magazine (month?, year?)

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are the tables //thanks for fixing my format//

```
ADV_COST
--------
PAGE_SIZE  
MAG_ID  
COST

//SAMPLE DATA ADV_COST//  
PAGE_SIZE                MAG_ID       COST
-------------------- ---------- ----------
1/25 PAGE                     1         40  
1/8  PAGE                     1         60  
1/6  PAGE                     1         65  
...


ADS
--------
AD_ID  
ADV_ID  
PAGE_SIZE  
MAG_ID  
START_DATE  
PURCH_DATE  
NUM_ISSUES



//SAMPLE DATA ADS//  
     AD_ID     ADV_ID PAGE_SIZE     MAG_ID START_DAT PURCH_DAT NUM_ISSUES
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
         1          5 1/4 PAGE           1 01-APR-11 01-MAR-11         4
...
```

---

Here's the question:
Whirlpool ADV_ID=6; HOUSES: MAG_ID=1;

"How much money did Whirlpool spend in advertising in HOUSES this month?, this year?"

help please, thanks!

This is what I tried.

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(COST)  
  2  FROM DVD_ADV_COST A, DVD_ADS B  
  3  WHERE A.MAG_ID = B.MAG_ID  
  4  AND B.ADV_ID = 6  
  5  AND B.MAG_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Did you have issues when trying to put the question in a good format? http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: Fixed the code formatting for you. Future reference: Lines in questions that are indented by four spaces will be formatted as code blocks (or select text and click the `{ }` icon in the editor). That said, would you share what you've tried? Do you have no idea where to start?

Comment: Is the cost field per issue? Per month? How many issues per month?

Comment: I'd guess you should also be joining A and B on PAGE_SIZE in your WHERE clause

Comment: The sql code i gave runs, but it doesn't add anything.  I haven't tried doing the between dates yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(B.COST * A.NUM_ISSUES) AS TOTAL_COST
  FROM DVD_ADS A, 
       DVD_ADV_COST B
 WHERE B.MAG_ID = A.MAG_ID
   AND B.PAGE_SIZE = A.PAGE_SIZE
   AND A.ADV_ID = 6
   AND A.MAG_ID = 1
```

and then add your date range to the WHERE clause as well

If it's not returning any data, make sure that you actually have entries for ADV_ID = 6.... your example show an entry for 5

Comment: Are the tables called DVD_ADS and DVD_ADV_COST or ADS and ADV_COST

Comment: dvd_ads and dvd_adv_cost; I shortened it to make it easier to type for everyone

Comment: I just checked the data in the ads table and there are no adv_ids that = 6.  There's the reason it isn't adding anything up..